# Calculating Probability in Bayesian Networks

Tags: bayesian, bayesian-network

I'm trying to work out how to calculate the outcome probability $\Pr(Y)$ for the following BN:

[image: Bayes Network]

I know the joint probability $\Pr(a,b,c,Y) = \Pr(a) \Pr(b \mid a) \Pr(c) \Pr(Y \mid b,c)$ (which I'll call $J$ from now on for ease) and [then I applied Bayes' theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euyK2.jpg) (steps included here) to $\Pr(Y \mid b,c)$ to get $\frac{\Pr(b \mid Y,c)\Pr(c \mid Y) \Pr(Y)}{\Pr(b \mid c) \Pr(c)}$ which can then be inserted into the joint probability equation and used to find $\Pr(Y)$. Is this correct? Are there any further steps I can take to simplify this solution? Thank you!

Comment: you can find everything you need here https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.09217.pdf

Comment: Is there a reason that you used lower case letters $a,b,c$ but an upper case letter $Y$? Maybe you want to indicate that the values of the variables other than $Y$ are already fixed to some value?